# bash sort alphanumeric buildnumber

Tags: bash, macos, gnu

I have a list of buildnumbers which I get from my buildserver, like this:

```
1.0.0.b1
1.0.0.b10
1.0.0.b11
1.0.0.b12
1.0.0.b13
1.0.0.b14
1.0.0.b15
1.0.0.b16
1.0.0.b17
1.0.0.b18
1.0.0.b19
1.0.0.b2
1.0.0.b20
1.0.0.b21
1.0.0.b22
1.0.0.b3
1.0.0.b4
1.0.0.b5
1.0.0.b6
1.0.0.b7
1.0.0.b8
1.0.0.b9
```

now I need to sort this where I expect the highes buildnumber on the bottom like this:

```
1.0.0.b1
1.0.0.b2
1.0.0.b3
1.0.0.b4
1.0.0.b5
1.0.0.b6
1.0.0.b7
1.0.0.b8
1.0.0.b9
1.0.0.b10
1.0.0.b11
1.0.0.b12
1.0.0.b13
1.0.0.b14
1.0.0.b15
1.0.0.b16
1.0.0.b17
1.0.0.b18
1.0.0.b19
1.0.0.b20
1.0.0.b21
1.0.0.b22
```

now in linux with GNU sort it is easy - just use sort -V

But this has also to work on macOS where I do not have any experience on it, but from testing I know -V does not work there.

I tried with

```
sort -t . -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n
```

but no luck there.

I want to have it sorted by Version/buildnumber, e.g.

1.1.3.b5 is higher than 1.0.3.b66

what have I missed here? Can you please help me? Also, unfortuneatly, installing homebrew coreutils are not an option

thank you,
br Alex

Comment: You can fix your version number by adding the missing dot between the alphabetic and numeric parts: `sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)\([[:digit:]]\)/\1.\2/'`

Comment: @ceving as these are buildnumbers straight from our build system I do not want to mess with them as I reuse it to get some artifactory from the artifactory store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your real full list won't have all `b` versions. You'll need to split field 4 into two keys; one for the alpha part and one for the numeric part.

```
$: sort -t. -k1n -k2n -k3n -k4.1,4.1 -k4.2n vnums
1.0.0.a5
1.0.0.a10
1.0.0.a13
1.0.0.a19
1.0.0.b1
1.0.0.b6
1.0.0.b8
1.0.0.b9
1.0.0.b12
1.0.0.b14
1.0.0.b17
1.0.0.b20
1.0.0.b21
1.0.0.b22
1.0.0.c3
1.0.0.c7
1.0.0.c15
1.0.0.c16
1.0.0.d2
1.0.0.d4
1.0.0.d11
1.0.0.d18
1.0.3.b66
1.1.3.b5
```

Note the limiting of the alpha column of field 4 to a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the forth key as composed of subfields:

```
sort -t. -k1n,1 -k2n,2 -k3n,3 -k4.1,4.1 -k4.2n
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl one-liner

Assuming that there is no more than 6 digit (or fixed size), `sprintf "%06", $&` will sort over numbers left padded with 0:

```
perl -e 'sub v{"@_"=~s/\d+/sprintf"%06d",$&/ger}print sort{v($a)cmp v($b)} <>' inputfile
```

Comment: While I always recommend leading zeros when you have the option, I wouldn't edit version numbers. They are what they are.

Comment: if you run the command you will see the version numbers are not changed, instead a "key" is computed and used by compare function

Comment: Gotcha. Like a Schwartzian.

Comment: Almost, schwartzian will look like `print map$_->[0],sort{$a->[1]cmp$b->[1]}map[$_,s/\d+/sprintf"%06d",$&/ger],<>`, maybe more efficient because transform will be called once

Comment: Thanks, but I want to stick with bash in this case, since this is part of a shell script